# Fatal error: Uncaught PHP exception in DateTimeZone::__construct()?

Tags: php

This is going to be a bit difficult to explain but I will try my best to explain it as good as i can.

I am passing Data from an `input textfield` on one page `(page1.php)` to a `Select form` on another page `(page2.php)`. 
This works as should.

the `Select Form` contains some `PHP timezones` and when a timezone is selected, the page page will echo the current time for that timezone.
This also works as it should.

The problem is when I enter a timezone name in the input textfield on `(page1.php)` , it will show the name in the Select Form on `(page2.php)` BUT it will not echo its current time and it will throw out this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (London)' in page2.php:16 Stack trace: #0 on line 16.
```

when infact the timezone London exists in the `Select Form Options` and if I enter/search for London directly in the select form, it will echo the current time for that timezone but it will NOT if the timezone name was entered in the input textfield on page1.php and it was passed to the select form on page2.php!

here is what I have on page2.php:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $timezone2 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    function get_timezone_offset( $remote_tz ) {
        $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone ( $remote_tz ); ----->>> Line 16 is here.

        $datetime2 = new DateTime ("now", $timezone2);

        $offset = $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
        return $offset;

    }

$offset = get_timezone_offset($timezone2);

}

?>

<?php
$options = array();
$options[$_POST["location"]] = $_POST["location"]; <<<<<<----- Data from input textfield on page1.php
$options["Africa/Addis_Ababa"] = "Addis Ababa"; <<<<<<----- Select Form Options
$options["Europe/London"] = "London"; <<<<<<----- Select Form Options

?>
```

and here is the Select Form on page2.php

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" class="myForm" method="post" action="page2.php">
  <select style="font-size:9px;" name="timezone2" id="timezone2" class="timezone2">
                        <?php
                    foreach($options as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" label="'. $value .'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $_POST["location"]; ?>"><?php echo $_POST["location"]; ?></option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="myBtn" style="position:relative; float:left; width: 228px; margin-top:50px; margin-left:350px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Search"/></div>

</form>
```

and here is the input textfield on page1.php

```
<form method="post" action="../page2.php">
  <input name="location" type="text" value="Search"/>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Timezone value should be `Europe/London` not simply `London`; so check what's being sent back from your form

Comment: @MarkBaker, I know that and thats why I am using the `$options = array();` so it will convert Europe/London to London in the select form and this works if the London was entered/searched for directly in select form.

Comment: The error was pretty clear, PHP doesn't understand what time zone that is since there's no `London` for timezone. And Mark told you the same yet you persist. So, have fun debugging something while being so stubborn. Bottom line - you gave the wrong value to `new DateTimeZone()`, work with that and find your way out.

Comment: @N.B. i'm not being stubborn. lol I just didn't Understand exactly what Mark said first time round. now I read it again, i think I might have found a solution. not sure but i will do a few tests and will update this post.

Comment: Your problem is that you have invalid data in your dropdown which you use without checking. God knows how you constructed that dropdown and what you actually want to achieve, but there are functions which will tell you which time zones are supported by your server. Consequently, those are time zones that PHP can work with. What you're doing is posting some non-validated data and sticking it into DateTimeZone constructor, wondering why it doesn't work. Read the answer provided, try not to rush and check what people here tell you to pay attention to.

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this wrong for a few reasons. Firstly, the list of possible timezones is finite so get rid of the text field and just use a dropdown.

Second, you can remove\rename the items in the dropdown all you want but just remember that since you are saving the offset and not the tz name you can never go back (my example will show you exactly why that is if you play with it). Usually, it is best to store the name and not the offset so that you can manage daylight savings properly. You'll notice that to get this system to work I need to call date('I') to find out if it is daylight savings which is really bad (just because it's daylight saving in my server TZ doesn't mean it is in the users TZ). If you saved the TZ name instead you could defer that logic to PHP and just use whatever offset it currently is. This may not seem important in this simplistic example but if you ever tried to store that offset or calculate future\past times using it you'll definitely have troubles.

One other tiny thing is that it is odd to put function definitions inside of 'if' statements. In PHP all function definitions are global so it will be available regardless of whether the 'if' condition is true. The problem with doing that is now you've obscured your logic with no gain. It is easier and clearer to put that elsewhere.

I've rewritten your code to be a little nicer and to actually work as you are using it but I've left out a few details (like aliasing the TZ names [which you seem to have a handle on how to do] and switching to using TZ names instead of offsets [because that may break other code you have]) but I encourage you to fix those as well.

```
<?php
$tz_offset=0;

function get_offset_time($offset=0) {
    $original=new DateTime("now");
    $timezoneName=timezone_name_from_abbr("", $offset, date('I'));
    if(!$timezoneName) die('ERROR: Unknown timezone \''.($offset/3600).'\'');
    $oTZ=new DateTimezone($timezoneName);
    $modified = $original->setTimezone($oTZ);
    return $modified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
function get_timezone_offset($tz_name=null) {
    if(!$tz_name) return 0; // If we have invalid data then return before we error
    $tz=new DateTimeZone($tz_name);
    $dt=new DateTime("now", $tz);
    return $tz->getOffset($dt);
}
function enumerate_tz($tz_select=null) {
    global $tz_offset;
    $tz_ident=DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
    foreach($tz_ident as $val) {
        $tmp_offset=get_timezone_offset($val);
        if($val=='UTC'||$tmp_offset) 
            echo '<option value="'.$val.'" '. ($tmp_offset==$tz_offset?' selected':''). '>'. 
            $val. ' [ '.($tmp_offset/3600).' ]'.  // If you'd like to customize the viewable names for each TZ you may do so here
                    '</option>';
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['tz_input']) && $_POST['tz_input']) {
    $tz_input=htmlentities($_POST['tz_input']);
    $tz_offset=get_timezone_offset($tz_input);
}
echo '<html><title>Timezone Select</title><body>'.
'<p>The current timezone offset is: '. ($tz_offset? ($tz_offset/3600): '0'). '</p>';
echo '<p>The current time is: '. get_offset_time($tz_offset). '</p>';
echo '<form method=post><select name=tz_input>';
enumerate_tz($tz_offset); // You'll notice that this list duplicates many of the timezones so that after selecting one the next 
                                    // time through it'll often select a different one. If you want to fix that you'll need to save the actually offset name instead of an offset.
echo '</select><input type=submit value=Search />'.
    '</form></body>';
?>
```

EDIT: One other thing to note is that PHP's timezone_name_from_abbr() function is not complete. Some timezone offsets will not return a TimeZone name. You must account for that as well. For example, even though PHP understands the 'Pacific/Midway' timezone it cannot find it when doing a reverse lookup. I've updated the code so that won't cause a hard error anymore.

EDIT2: I can see that you aren't going to be happy until someone shows you how to shine that turd. Here you go:

```
function getOptionDX($val, $option_array) {
    if(!isset($option_array)||!is_array($option_array)||!count($option_array)>0||!$val) return null;
    $val=htmlentities($val);
    if(isset($option_array[$val])) return $val;
    $new_val=array_search($val, $option_array);
    return $new_val!==FALSE?$new_val: null;
}
```

Add this to your code and replace the call to htmlentities with a call to this:

```
$timezone2 = getOptionDX($_POST['timezone2'], $options);
```

Lastly, change this line:

```
if($timezone2) $offset = get_timezone_offset($timezone2);
```

If the user enters the TZ manually and it is correct then skip page2.php. This is as close to an answer as can be given if you don't want to change anything. The fact is that your logic is flawed in the first place (that is not meant to be a jab but it is true).

EDIT3: IDK what was wrong but here is my full code listing with the fixes you asked for:

```
<?php
$offset=0; $timezone2='';
$options = array();
$options["Africa/Addis_Ababa"] = "Addis Ababa";
$options["Europe/London"] = "London";
$options["America/Chicago"] = "The Windy City";

function getOptionDX($val, $option_array) {
    if(!isset($option_array)||!is_array($option_array)||!count($option_array)>0||!$val) return null;
    $val=htmlentities(ucwords(strtolower($val)));
    if(isset($option_array[$val])) return $val;
    $new_val=array_search($val, $option_array);
    return $new_val!==FALSE?$new_val: null;
}
function get_timezone_offset( $remote_tz ) {
    $timezone2=new DateTimeZone($remote_tz);
    $datetime2=new DateTime("now", $timezone2);
    $offset=$timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
    return $offset;
}
if(isset($_POST['location'])) {
    $addLoc=getOptionDX($_POST['location'], $options);
    if(isset($addLoc)) $options[$addLoc]=$_POST['location'];
    else header('Location: '. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
}
if(isset($_POST['timezone2'])) {
    $timezone2=htmlentities($_POST['timezone2']);
    $offset=get_timezone_offset($timezone2);
}
if(isset($_GET['page2'])) {
?>
<form method=post action=?page2>
<select name=timezone2>
<?php foreach($options as $key=>$value) echo "\t".'<option value="'. $key .'"'.(get_timezone_offset($key)==$offset?' selected':'').'>'.$value.'</option>'."\n"; ?>
</select>
<input type=hidden name=location type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['location']; ?>"/>
</div>
<input type=submit value=Search>
</form>
<p>Current Offset: <?php echo $offset/3600; ?></p>
<p>Current Time: <?php echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?> UTC</p>
<p>Current Time: <?php echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+$offset).' '. $timezone2; ?> </p>
<?php
} else {
?>
<form method=post action=?page2>
<input name=location type=text value=""/>
<button type=submit>Search</button>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

I've tested this and know it works, if that isn't enough to answer your question then I give up. I'm starting to think that you really want a way to invent new timezones which don't exist. That isn't possible. You can alias those which already exists as I've done here which is as close as you're ever going to get. Logically, time zones can only range from -12:00 to +12:00 and nearly every known timezone is already accounted for so you really have no choice but to rethink your design if this isn't enough.

Comment: it's great that you've taken time and made an effort to explain and write this code and i appreciate it but I am not sure what this has to do with my question!

Comment: Didn't you ask to be pointed in the right direction? This code does just what you seem to have wanted except it doesn't error (or at least it does so gracefully). I've also pointed out several problems you're about to encounter which you almost certainly don't see coming yet. Trust me, this information is going to be more useful to you than you may see ATM and there are a few large differences between the way I did this and the way you did it. The actual bug in your code is so obvious I'm not even going to bother mentioning why your code fails. Throw it out.

Comment: @N.B., I'm not sure what your problem is mate, not everyone was born with all sorts of knowledge and if you know a bit more than someone else then there is no need to keep bragging off about it and showing off by leaving absolutely useless comments. I don't really understand what your contribution is to this post right now apart from "acting" like "Mr I know it all" but can't be asked to reply which is a bit weird. if you cannot help then be on your way!

Comment: @krowe, Okay I understand your logic now (after readying your explanation for the second time) but you seem to just made the first lot of my code better without taking into account that my question was about passing the data correctly from the input textfield to the select form!! i really think you've missed my point and its not your fault. it my fault as i haven't explained it correctly.

Comment: I am not and don't need to consider the TZ daylight for this example. at least for now.

Comment: See my second update for a better explanation of what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Sorry, I got confussed for a minute. Refresh and look at it again now.

Comment: Sorry but the new updates will not do anything! in fact the only thing it does is that it will throw out a wrong Time for each timezone!

Comment: OK, well now I've updated with my full test script done your way. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Okay mate, I know it says not to use words like Thanks etc on stackoverflow but you deserve one mate. you went way out of your way to help me out and I appreciate it. However, I don't even know where to start with your final code as i see things like `<form method=post action=?page2>` which is alien to me especially the action part of the form! also, when i run the code on the server, all i see an input textfield and a button and nothing happens! I guess I am going to have to listen to your advice and leave it.

Comment: If you type something into the field and press the button you should see that item replace whatever timezone it matches on the next page. The code assumes that the final version will have entries for every possible timezone (or at least those you'd like to allow). Also, this file should be all you need; it does the job of both of your pages just to be clear.

Comment: The action property of a form tag is just the URL you like the form to POST\GET (depending on the method setting of the same tag) to. action=?page2 means that the form will post to the same page but it'll add the URL parameter to the address. This means that if the page is at http://myserv.net/tz_test.php this form will post to http://myserv.net/tz_test.php?page2 . We check to see whether page2 is set and if it is then we display page2 instead of just the text field and button.

Comment: Ohh ya, you probably aren't seeing anything happening because the timezone name you are typing doesn't exist. Try typing 'london' (with a small L) in the text field or type 'america/Chicago'.

Comment: okay, I understand better now. but I need the process to be done on two different pages due to design of the site! I am not going to bother you anymore mate. I really appreciate your continuous support and help. I have now gone through javascript way. easier and as far as i know over 95% of computers these days run javascript and the ones that don't then they are backwards :D.

Comment: although I wish i could get an straight forward answer to my original question after 2 days of posting this as i preferred using PHP instead of javascript as all i've got on stackoverflow was either criticism or people kept changing my code and returned it back to me without actually finding out what the question was about! but hey, I'm always grateful.

Comment: I hope you didn't take anything I've said as negative criticism. Mark Baker has already explained why you had the original error. One possible solution to that error is my getOptionDX() function. It seems that the question is not exactly clear to us because, as far as I can tell, the solution is right in front of you.

Time is one of those areas which is deceptively difficult in any programming language. I still think that your design is flawed which is what is making this so hard. I'll say this one last time, *you shouldn't have users TYPE in timezones; use a dropdown only*.

Comment: Yep. That still doesn't change what I said, twice, 'use a dropdown only'. There are only so many timezones possible; it's OK to list them all. Anytime you can it is best to avoid user input which can fail. This detail is also adding a lot of complexity to this problem. I think you still aren't following the basic problem going on here. You can only send valid timezones to the DateTimeZone constructor. Therefore, when you allow user input you're going to NEED to convert that input to an ACTUAL timezone. london, London, Blankshire, and Teds Goat farm are all example of string which are NOT TZs.